# .NET platform web hosting

Tags: .net, hosting

What should I do to host on my own machine a .NET web application(ASP.NET, Silverlight) with support Sql Server and services(RIA, WCF)?

What should I install and configure so others can interact with my application via the internet ?

It's some administration API which I can install on a PC and by which I can upload my app like in professional hosting?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can run your asp.net app locally you nearly have anything to make it available worldwide (provided you have a permanent connection to the web with a static IP).

Install IIS (Internet Information Server - included in all Windows Versions except Home) and then deploy your app to your IIS. Thats it!

Reading from your comments I guess you are better off using a server and not trying to hosting yourself. Getting out of your dorm network may be hard to impossible and likely wouldn't be allowed anyways.

There are sites like [Brinkster](http://www.brinkster.com/hosting/FreeDeveloper.aspx) that offer free ASP.Net hosting. Maybe that suits you better.

Comment: Thanks for this ASP hosting ;) But I want own hosting couse profesional hosting with all .net features support and sql server 2008 are expensive :/ Soon I left dorm and hope then I buy router and do my hosting ;)

Answer (score 1):

Working from the assumption that you don't want to spend a lot of money on it, [go here](http://www.dyndns.com/).

Comment: I live in dorm where we don't have external ip ? Will this work ?

Comment: If you don't have a public ip you'dd probably either need a tunnel or a port-forward. Since web uses port 80 and 81 (which is widly used) getting a port-forward from your dorm sounds like something that might not happen, so you might need to set up a tunnel to some server that actually has a public IP.

Comment: If he had some server with a public IP where he could install software (DynDNS) and could tunnel into it would likely be a more simple solution to just host there ;)